# Is there a SQL function that can help me reverse an order of a string?

Tags: sql, regex, hana

I have this string 'Year/Month' and I want to make it 'Month/Year'.

Now I've looked into the `REVERSE` function, but that would convert something like `'2023/10'` into `'01/3202'`, which is not what I want.

Then I thought of a regex, but I was not sure how to use a regex function to identify the '/' and move everything in front of the '/' to the end of my string.

Maybe something like `REGEX_REPLACE` could work? Have never used this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `REGEX_REPLACE(column, '(\d+)/(\d+)', '$2/$1')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data is always formatted as you describe and there is no need for a sanity check then one straightforward approach would be.

```
SELECT RIGHT('2023/10',2) + '/'+ LEFT('2023/10',4)
```

Comment: hi this was the right answer thank you so much

Comment: No problem. I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using string operators. I write an answer in PostgreSQL, but almost every SQL database have this feature in a relatively same manner and you should just read the documentation.

(Edit: **I've modified it a bit, and now it works on MySQL too**)

As written in PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) we have a `substring` function and a `concat` function. So all you need to do is getting the last two charactetrs from a 'YYYY/MM' string, concat it with a '/' character, and concat the result with the first four characters.

```
select concat(substring('2023/10' from 6 for 2), '/', substring('2023/10' from 1 for 4))
// response: '10/2023'
```